# Can the system check for "[enter code here]" in the text?

Tags: feature-request, editing

I wanted to answer [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/175317/33055), and while doing so decided to change the two commands in the text to preformatted text. IIRC I selected the text in the rendered output, and not (as I should have) in the `textarea`, after which I  hit `{}` to get the preformatted text, and nothing happened (at least not to the text I selected).

I noticed my mistake, went to the text area and did the operation again after which the backquotes around the text appeared as expected (and I also did changed the second command the same way).

I finished my answer and all seemed fine, except that, when coming back to the question, after a few minutes later, I noticed that the top of the question now had `Enter code here` [at the top of the text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/175317/2). Had I missed that when I first read the Q? No, the history indicates I inserted this, probably by hitting the `{}` while I had no text selected in the textarea (but in the rendered area).

Since this insertion occurred outside of my scroll window, and was not close to the edit I made later, I never noticed.

I have seen these insertions before (reviewing edits) and now that it happened to me, it seems easy to overlook when it happens. Could the system be changed to complain about this unaltered inserted text "`[enter code here]`", at least when it occurs at the beginning of a question/answer?

Comment: Should probably do that for "enter image description here" too.

Comment: I only have seen this with the code message but it can be applied to every placeholder text for any of the inserts (bold, italics etc).